# Is the big bang an ongoing process?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

Was all the energy that is the universe today, present at that femtosecond theory has pushed back to or was there an influx of energy for a period of time?

My question was: is the big bang like a pin prick in an infinite balloon of water? Initially, you have very high pressure, then as the hole expands the pressure drops but the flow doesn't stop.

In the case of the universe is the big bang still pouring gluons and muons in everywhere at about the same rate as it always has, it's just that over this much larger volume it is less dramatic than the first few centuries. Does our universe create a back pressure at its various stages that would explain the changes in rate of expansion over time?

It is equally likely I am
fundamentally misunderstanding what it means to be in an expanding universe.

I suspect it's fairly obvious to those that might answer that I've watched more science documentaries than is healthy but fail to comprehend most of the wikipedia pages describing the physics and maths that support them. I expect you see lots of these stupid questions and I suspect this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it.